# iOS app release without launch screens

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a small question about iOS launch images.
I have to use dynamic image (customer logos instead of fixed logo) in launch image.
So I am thinking of setting a ViewContoller in between launch and login screen with dynamically set image, and add black launch images as app launch images.
(launch image display time is very low and this will be acceptable to our customers)

app supports both iOS 7 and 8

1) I add LaunchScreen.xib and make it black

2) for older iOS versions adding black images.

My question is can i just not add any images ? is there a way to get the app approved without launch images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a launch image otherwise Apple will not allow it in the store. They're pretty strict about this.